# Why saving an image from the canvas to the local system on Android doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, canvas, local-storage

I have referenced [this](http://www.nihilogic.dk/labs/canvas2image/) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9926152/phonegap-android-how-to-save-the-capture-image-from-camera-in-the-sd-card), but I still have questions why
the code here doesn't work?

```
var canvas;
$(document).ready(function(){
"use strict";
$(' #test_local_storage_btn ').bind('click', function(){
"use strict";
canvas= document.getElementById('drawing_plate');

alert("test_local_storage_btn");
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, get_FileSys,    request_fail);
});//function and bind. 

});//function and ready. 

function request_fail(){
 "use strict";
 alert("request FS failed");
}

function get_FileSys(fileSystem){
"use strict";
alert("request file system OK");
fileSystem.root.getFile("/sdcard/story_repository/test.png",{create:    true, exclusive: false},get_file_entry,get_file_fail);

}
function get_file_fail(){}
function get_file_entry(fileEntry){
"use strict";
alert("Get file entry successfully.");
fileEntry.createWriter(gotFileWriter,create_writer_fail);
} 

function gotFileWriter(writer){
"use strict";
writer.onwrittened= function (evt){
writer.write(canvas.toDataURL("image/png"));
};
}

function create_writer_fail(){
alert("create_writer_fail");
}
```

I think this instrument **writer.write(canvas.toDataURL("image/png"));**  should work,but it didn't.

What I don't understand is the **canvas.toDataURL("image/png")** returns a string, and it should be written into the file. But nothing is created...
According to the the link [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9926152/phonegap-android-how-to-save-the-capture-image-from-camera-in-the-sd-card), the variable photo return its' value(photo.value) and it works. But now, as I do the similar thing, why doesn't it work?
I just want an explain. Thank u!!

**UPDATE: I work on PhoneGap and [this](http://www.nihilogic.dk/labs/canvas2image/) doesn't work.**
**/      **

Comment: obvious question: do you have phonegap's libraries included?

Comment: Yes, of course I did.
It's just a separate js file which is included by the index.html

Comment: try cleaning up your code a little, [jshint](http://www.jshint.com/) might help...

Comment: @JKirchartz       Updated. Thank you for the tool.  But I don't always use "use strict"; so that I don't put the instruction everywhere which the editor warns.

Comment: yeah, they're kinda big on promoting "use strict"...

Comment: that's your answer                
          http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23043014/convert-canvas-to-imageuri