# convert canvas to imageURI

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, canvas

I develop application using `Phonegap` (`Cordova`) and I have a problem trying to convert canvas to imageURI and to save it into sdcard.

Here is my code:

```
function saveCanvasAsImage(imageURI) {

            var gotFileEntry = function(fileEntry) {
                var gotFileSystem = function(fileSystem) {
                    var d = new Date();
                    var n = d.getTime();
                    // copy the file
                    fileEntry.moveTo(fileSystem.root.feelathome, n + ".jpg", null, null);
                };
                // get file system to copy or move image file to
                window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFileSystem, fsFail);
                alert("Image Capture Success");
            };
            //resolve file system for image
            window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI(document.getElementById("canvas").toDataURL("image/png").replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, ""), gotFileEntry, fsFail);

    }
//file system fail
function fsFail(error) {
    alert("failed with error code: " + error.code);
}
```

and i'm got error failed 5
where i'm wrong?

Comment: What is drawn in canvas? The only one attempt to draw something (image) in it is commented out. And what is variable "path" in "base64" function used for?

Comment: as you see i did not used the path variable. he is there because i tested something you can ignore it. second inside the canvas i have some images. i tried to convert those images into one and save it in my app folder. thanks.

Comment: Okay, but what about images in canvas? I mean, you created canvas, got it context and saved empty canvas as base64 in this code. Did you delete lines with adding images to this new canvas, or do you want to use already existing canvas?

Comment: i don't mined about the lines i'm just try to save it

Comment: Well, now about "getImageURI" function... It is supposed to get image URI, not base64 string. Does "window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI" end up with calling "fsFail" function?

Comment: i change my code to something simple. now i got an error message because my canvas converter isn't good enough.

Comment: You still try to resolve base64 string as URI (which are 2 different kind of things) in "resolveLocalFileSystemURI", don't you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Canvas doesn't work correctly in most versions of android's webview.

To be able to convert correctly a canvas to a file in any version of android, you can use the Canvas2ImagePlugin : https://github.com/devgeeks/Canvas2ImagePlugin